# htaccess: replace slash in query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### Context

I have a desktop app, and I'm creating a single mobile page that explains "this is a desktop app" and contains a "go to site anyway" link back to the original page the user tried to visit.

### Desired Result

I would like someone visiting `m.mysite.com/somepage` to view `m.mysite.com/index.php?page=somepage`.

### Current Code

`RewriteRule m\.mysite\.com/(.*) m.mysite.com/index.php?page=$1 [R,L]`

### Issue

The trouble is that `somepage` sometimes contains `/` or `?`, which break the link.

### Desired Action

How can I replace `/` and `?` with the special characters `!` and `,` in `somepage`, but not in the rest of the URL?

**Aside:** (I know it is cleaner to encode them, but I would rather not enable slash encoding in my URLs for security, so I would rather convert them back on `m.mysite.com/index.php`).

Comment: @anubhava it's a subdomain - I can get `m.mysite.com/index.php` to load just fine.

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess? Also what happens when you enter `m.mysite.com/somepage` in browser?